# File ownership on building docker images

Tags: file, docker, file-permissions

I want to set up file permissions for files I add to a docker image. I have this simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:utopic

WORKDIR /app
RUN groupadd -g 1000 baz && useradd -u 1000 -g baz baz -d /app -s /bin/false
RUN chown baz:baz /app && chmod g+s /app
# want this to be have group baz
ADD foo /app/
```

Building this with `docker build -t abc .` where there is a `foo` file in `.` creates an image. However, the permissions on `/app/foo` inside is not what I want.

```
docker run abc ls -la     
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 baz  baz  4096 Sep  2 23:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 37 root root 4096 Sep  3 07:27 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  419 Sep  2 21:43 foo
```

Note that file `foo` doesn't belong to group `baz` despite [the setgid bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories) being set on the `/app` dir. I could use `RUN chown -R baz:baz /app` after adding the files, but that casues the a copy of the layer to be created (Note the size of the two layers below):

```
docker history abc | head -n 3
IMAGE               CREATED              CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
b95a3d798873        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c chown -R baz:baz /app                419 B               
7e007196c116        About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:2b91d9890a9c392390   419 B
```

**Is there some way to get around this and have the ownership of files added be what I want?**

Comment: Doesn't the output `-rw-rw-r--  1 baz  baz   419 Sep  2 21:43 foo` indicate that `foo` belongs to group `baz`?

Comment: @WaleedKhan I had pasted the wrong output. That was from a run where I `chmod`ed the foo file after adding it to the image.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want the ownership/group specified as a separate step/layer?

Comment: @AlexLynham mostly image size. In this trivial case it's not a issue, but if I add a few large files into the image `chown`ing them will create a copy of the layer with same size as previous (as seen in the `docker history` command).

Comment: Yes, but because of way the layers are built up, surely the image size will stay the same, rather than increase? The individual layer (that is, image) will be the same, but the final image that's the sum total of all images will be the same size as if the second image didn't exist?

Comment: @AlexLynham the second layer has the same size as the first. The final image size is the sum of its layers (if I understand correctly). Try appending `RUN chown baz:baz /app/foo` to the above Dockerfile using a sizeable `foo` file. Build it once before and once after with two diffrent tags and you'll see the difference in image size.

Comment: Ah okay, maybe it's my understanding that is wrong then. I always assumed that for permissions-like tasks where the file was the same that the files were not added together for the final size at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adding `foo` directly, you could pack it as a tar-archive and set permissions for a specific UID/GID. Here is a post on how to do it:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61004/force-the-owner-and-group-for-the-contents-of-a-tar-file

After that you can just untar it within your Docker image (`ADD` untars automagically). You should see the permissions preserved without an additional layer.