# Is ti possible to build the same linux docker image on windows when file permissions involved?

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, file-permissions, docker-for-windows

Lets have a `Dockerfile`, which is adding some large file to a linux image:

```
FROM busybox
ADD some_really_large_file /
```

I would like to build this image on windows and I need the file to have some specific file permissions, for example: `-rw-------` (`600`).

Is it possible to build such image on windows without having to `RUN` the `chmod` command, which would double the images size?

My question can be also understood as: Can I fix the docker security warning:

> SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have `-rwxr-xr-x` permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.

Could be for example the `Windows Subsystem for Linux` used for this task somehow?

Comment: I recommend installing Linux (perhaps in some virtual machine) on your laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following question helped me to find a solution using **GNU tar** (e.g. inside of `Windows Subsystem for Linux`):

- [File ownership on building docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32363708/1857897)

First, "tar" your data with `-p` option to preserve permissions and `--mode` to set the desired permissions:

```
tar -czvpf some_really_large_file.tar.gz --mode='a-rwx,u+rw' some_really_large_file
```

Second, because `ADD` untars automagically, use the archive instead of the original file in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM busybox
ADD some_really_large_file.tar.gz /
```